# Join single variable to multiple variables in r data.table

Tags: r, data.table

DT1 holds the mapping for all IDs, DT2 holds relationships between IDs.

I'd like to join the mappings from DT1 directly to both IDs in DT2.

Example datasets below:

```
# Join a mapping to multiple variables.
library(data.table)

# Dataset with mappings.
set.seed(1)
dt1 <- data.table(id=1:10,
                  group=sample(letters[1:4], 10, replace=TRUE))

# > dt1
#     id group
#  1:  1     b
#  2:  2     b
#  3:  3     c
#  4:  4     d
#  5:  5     a
#  6:  6     d
#  7:  7     d
#  8:  8     c
#  9:  9     c
# 10: 10     a

# Dataset with relationship between IDs.
dt2 <- data.table(id1=1:5,
                  id2=6:10)

# > dt2
#    id1 id2
# 1:   1   6
# 2:   2   7
# 3:   3   8
# 4:   4   9
# 5:   5  10
```

I could of course use two joins, first on ID1, then on ID2. Another way of achieving what I want is first melting DT2, so all the ID values are a single variable before joining...

```
# Now melt, join group variable of DT1 to DT2, then cast again to obtain
# original structure.
dt2[, i := .I] # need an observation ID
dt2Long <- melt(dt2, id="i")
setkey(dt2Long, value)
dcast(dt2Long[dt1], i ~ variable, value.var=c("value", "group"))

#    i value_id1 value_id2 group_id1 group_id2
# 1: 1         1         6         b         d
# 2: 2         2         7         b         d
# 3: 3         3         8         c         c
# 4: 4         4         9         d         c
# 5: 5         5        10         a         a
```

This gives the desired result, but I would like to know if something like the following is possible (i.e. merging a single variable with two variables)?

```
setkey(dt1, id)
dt1[dt2, on=c("id1", "id2")]
```

Comment: A possible alternative way: ```dt2[, `:=` (grp_id1 = dt1$group[match(id1, dt1$id)], grp_id2 = dt1$group[match(id2, dt1$id)])]```

Comment: You could achieve the same without creating `i`. Also, why do you need it in a wide format. Long format is much more consice to work with. Just do `dt1[melt(dt2, measure = names(dt2)), on = c(id = "value")]` and leave it as is if you ask me

Comment: @DavidArenburg Very elegant solution, however, I need to retain the relationships between ID1 and ID2 and that is lost when not storing the original row number . Normally I agree with using data in long format, as you suggest, but in my case the data is a pedigree (animal, parent) and such a structure is expected as input by an external program.

Comment: Then I guess you could do `dt1[melt(dt2[, i := .I], "i"), on = c(id = "value")]` (the devel version 1.9.7 on GH, has a new `rowid` function too) similar to your original idea. This looks very efficient to me. I would do it the same way. If you need a wide format, wrapping this into `dcast` shouldn't cost much neither. All of the functions you are using here are fully optimized.

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg, that's pretty indeed.